# Meteor fire event if collection meets time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to update a document based on time, so for example:

I've got a collection `Questions`, with a field 'datetime_from'.
To show the question from that date, I use

```
return Questions.find({datetime_from:{$lt: Chronos.currentTime() }});
```

(Im using the `remcoder:chronos`) package.

Now I want to send an `raix:push` notification, when datetime_from meets the current time.

Also, another example:
I got a collection `Projects`, with a field 'stop'. Stop is the date when the project stops.
I want to update the document in the project to 'Finished' when current time meets 'Stop'.

How should I achieve this?

Yours,
L

Comment: https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron

Comment: @Sindis I dont think I need that package, since I get all times from the collections. I think I need something like `if(Questions.find({datetime_from:Chronos.currentTime()})){ Push.send{} }`

Comment: So basically you need to fire up event at given time, therefore you need something to run it for you, IMO cron job would be best

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this using:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
  var date = new Date();
  console.log(date);
  if( Projects.findOne({status: 'running', stop: {$lt: date}}) ){
    var finished = Projects.findOne({status: 'running', stop: {$lt: date}});
    Projects.update({_id: finished._id}, {$set: {status: 'finished'}});
  }
},1000);
```

On the server side